# Как подружить Flask и React js?

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

Есть Flask приложение:

```
app
 |-- app.py
 |
 |-- templates
        |-- index.html
```

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', name='Vasya')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="view"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

    let HelloWorld = React.createClass({
        render: function () {
            return <h1>Hello{{ name }}</h1>
        }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld />, document.getElementById('view'));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Передаю в html шаблон переменную с именем, вставляю в React шаблон, верный ли это подход ? Что бы не писать скрипты прямо в html файле, как организовать код в таком случае? и как после отделения скрипта от html файла передавать с сервера данные в шаблон если вся разметка в React рендерится с помощью javascript?

Попробовал вынести js код в одельный файл в папку static, соответственно в html подключил таким обазом:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.js') }}" type="text/babel"></script>
```

Если оставить вынесенный в отдельный файл React код без вставки переменной переданной с сервера

```
<h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>
```

в таком виде все хорошо:

```
let HelloWorld = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return <h1>Hello</h1>
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld />, document.getElementById('view'));
```

Но если я пытаюсь передать данные:

```
let HelloWorld = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return <h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld />, document.getElementById('view'));
```

То нечего в итоге не выходит и вылезает ошибка:

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `HelloWorld`.
```

На сколько я понимаю нужно передавать данные в уже скомпелированый реактом шаблон, но видимо во время передачи данных он еще не скомпелировался, как исправить положение ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, методом SSR (server side rendering), запускается сервер на node js (получаем изоморфное приложение) для рендеринга javascript. С главного сервера сначала посылаем шаблон с React приложением на рендер сервер, исполняем там javascript, получаем от него уже отрендереную страницу и отдаем ее на основном сервере. Это так же решает проблему с индексированием поисковыми системами, так как роботы вместо пустой станицы видят уже построенное DOM дерево.

Comment: А можно более подробно? с кодом / или ссылкой на гит?
Встала такая де задача, но решить пока не могу(

Answer (score 0):

Для тех, кому просто надо научиться подружить React и Flask в Pycharm, смотрите это видео:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YW8VG_U-m48&ab_channel=JoranBeasley
Я новичок, но у меня получилось. Я не знаю, почему учитель не создавал виртуальное окружение, я к такому не привык. Я сразу создал 2 папки flask-backend и react-frontend и в каждой из них использовал готовый установщик flask и React app в PyCharm