# Как убрать из строки табы и пробелы в Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как из строки убрать табы и новые строки?

> \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRussian Federation\t\t\t\t\t\t

Пробовал так, но не выходит:

```
nationality = (item.find('td', {'class': 'col2'}).text).replace('   ', '')
nationality = (item.find('td', {'class': 'col2'}).text).replace(' ', '')
nationality = (item.find('td', {'class': 'col2'}).text).replace('\n', '')
nationality = (item.find('td', {'class': 'col2'}).text).replace('\t', '')
nationality = (item.find('td', {'class': 'col2'}).text).replace('\n\t', '')
```

Comment: вы результат `.replace()` куда-нибудь присваиваете?

Comment: @MaxU да, неправильно сделал вставку кода. Исправил исходный пост.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как удалить все пробелы из строки в Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/359110/23044)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> s = '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRussian Federation\t\t\t\t\t\t'
>>> s.lstrip()
'Russian Federation\t\t\t\t\t\t'
>>> s.strip()
'Russian Federation'
```

Comment: хорошее решение !

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо ) Вы случайно мой сегодняшний вопрос не смотрели ? может будут мысли какие либо. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/719856/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-flask-%D0%B8-react-js

Answer (score 1):

Пусть строка находится в переменной `str`
Тогда: `' '.join(str.split())` даст нам строку `Russian Federation`

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split
Метод str.split() возвращает список слов между разделителями. Если разделитель не указан, либо `sep=None`, тогда в строке убираются все разделители и мы получаем список из слов `['Russian', 'Federation']`

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.join
Метод str.join() "склеивает" строку из списка. Строка, которую мы передали методу является разделителем. В данном случае это пробел `' '.join`.